# Dual Boot Windows/Ubuntu : System cannot boot from UEFI mode anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Here's a rundown of what happened:

1. I have a new MSI GF65 9SE laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 10 Home.
2. I made a partition in the main windows drive itself, disable fast startup, disable secure boot, and installed Ubuntu 20.04 there.
3. GRUB screen did not show up on restart, so it boots directly into Windows and I have to go to my newly installed Ubuntu box from the advanced startup options.
4. I log into Ubuntu this way, everything seems kinda OK so far.
5. This is where I messed up I think. I restored a timeshift backup snapshot from an external HDD to the Ubuntu box, I think i maybe picked the wrong options for the bootloader installation, everything went fine according to the logs though.
6. Then after the timeshift backup is restored and system auto-restarts, [I'm greeted with this screen](https://www.diskpart.com/screenshot/en/others/windows-10/winload-efi-missing.png)
7. Pressing Enter will just reload the screen, I have an additional option "Press f1 to enter recovery environment", which just reboots and takes me to the same screen, <kbd>ESC</kbd> will take me to BIOS.
8. So, basically, the only setting in the bios that will allow me to enter anything is setting it to LEGACY instead of UEFI and booting into a live Linux USB.
9. I did just that, deleted my old Ubuntu partitions and reinstalled Ubuntu on the same.
10. Now my laptop actually boots into Ubuntu directly. Setting it to legacy, and booting by default into ubuntu is the only way i can get into my computer now. I can access my windows files from here. But the data is not important, it's a fresh system.

Is there a way to repair this situation and take me back to how it was at step 4 at least? I've tried:

1. From Linux live USB and my ubuntu installation which boots from legacy, I tried repairing the windows MBR with solutions suggested [here](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-bootloader-linux/). The boot-repair tool didn't work because i'm booted from legacy, lilo didn't work, throwing a fatal error saying device is not a master and does not contain partitioning info or something like that. I checked the drive using Gparted and the drive seems to be GPT, not MBR.

Is my only solution here to set it to UEFI, use a windows recovery USB and attempt a repair?

Comment: If you have an UEFI system, you do not want to do anything with legacy. That just complicates and confuses system and may break it. Always have UEFI setting for booting installed systems & always boot in UEFI mode. Was your restore from timeshift an old BIOS/MBR install?  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm currently running boot-info from my Ubuntu through the legacy mode. This is the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bQRhp7B6Xd/
 ---
Was your restore from timeshift an old BIOS/MBR install?  -- I'm not sure, where do I check this?
---
use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install -- Could you please tell me what you need me to run, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Also, @oldfred, I cannot run auto-fix in the boot-repair tool even if i tried, It says to retry after booting from UEFI

Comment: You have UEFI system & UEFI install of Windows. But because mount of ESP - efi system partition missing from fstab, you must have tried to install the BIOS verison of grub even though you have UEFI boot entries that now refer to UUIDs that do not exist. Reboot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode, add Boot-Repair and run the full reinstall of grub in UEFI boot mode. Then only boot in UEFI mode. You have BIOS boot entries that will not work if you attempt to boot in BIOS mode & will just stop system.

Comment: @oldfred, I just booted into live installer through UEFI (it just worked this time),  I installed boot-repair. Do i have to change anything from the recommended settings before trying to run it? (In recommended settings, Under advanced options, GRUB Options tab, secure boot seems to be checked)

Comment: @oldfred, It seems UEFI goes back to secure boot mode after switching back from legacy. I disabled secure boot again and ran boot-repair like you said, from live installer, UEFI, (i unticked the Secure boot option in advanced options in boot-repair). It says boot has been repaired successfully, but it's booting to the same Blue Screen error again.

Comment: forgot to include the pastebin after the boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GQ9r2qCK8p/

Comment: It says boot repaired. Where are you getting blue screen? Do you get grub menu? Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu and boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu. Many with HP have needed UEFI update & only could change boot order inside UEFI settings (not UEFI menu). Grub only boots working Windows, so if Windows fast start up on, or it needs chkdsk you have to directly boot from UEFI or boot your Windows repair/recovery flash drive to change settings in Windows or make Windows repairs.

Comment: Where are you getting blue screen?  - restart after boot-repair, goes directly into the blue screen after the MSI logo, Do you get grub menu? - no, There are no options in the "boot" tab of the BIOS to select what to boot. It just has a boot order. It just shows Hard Disk as one single option among others. This Hard Disk is where both Windows and Ubuntu is installed for me. So, is there anything else I can try at all before Windows recovery?

Comment: Is there a sub-menu under hard disk? Does the UEFI settings & boot tab allow you to change items in boot menu? Did you update UEFI, many with HP have said they have to do that. Blue screen seems more like Windows issues. Is it still f8 to get Windows repair console as it starts to boot or not boot, do not use Windows.

Comment: @oldfred, There are no sub-menus in that tab unfortunately, just picking the priorities of the boot. There's no way to the recovery environment unless with a recovery USB. It goes directly from the MSI logo to the blue screen i showed above saying winload is missing. I don't think this is a windows issue since this happened after that timeshift backup was restored. Everything was fine before.

Comment: Do not know nor use Timeshift, but would not think any restore would change UEFI settings. It may change what a default UEFI setting then actually uses by changing the file UEFI expects to boot. A Ubuntu entry uses /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi & /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. Or the hard drive/fallback entry /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. The fallback entry is the same entry as booting an external drive, but most often a different file with just same name.  Did you do a full reinstall of grub, not just an update which updates boot menu? And have you updated UEFI?

Comment: I did a full reinstall of grub with the boot-repair when i ran it. No updates to UEFI.

Anyways, even with a boorrec repair from windows recovery USB, it's still giving the same blue screen. I just chose to reinstall windows and delete the old windows installation.